# How do I build the apache flex framework rsls?

Tags: apache-flex, ant, rsls

I tried **ant frameworks-rsls** but it doesn't work. I don't see any swz files just swfs.

Comment: ok from the framework directory I ran ant main frameworks-rsls. Seemed to work fine until it compiled air. I get compile errors and ant discontinues. anyone have this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Flex does not contain SWZ files.
The SWZ files were issued and signed by Adobe and cached by Flash Player for quick loading.
But since Adobe is no more developing Flex, Adobe will not be releasing SWZ files any more.
You will have to work with the SWF version of the RSLs.

Comment: Thanks. So now I just need to add the swf files in my ant build.xml